# Error 403 when uploading cropped image with Croppie to Laravel 8 Controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, http-status-code-403, croppie

I'm currently working on a Laravel 8 project in which I need to create cards with text and cropped images using the Croppie plugin.
Everything works perfectly locally.
However, once in production, when I send the cropped image to my controller, the server firewall interprets it most of the time as an attack and the server returns a 403 error.
Here is the information the firewall tells me :

> ID : 340029 Sévérité : CRITICALLabel : -
> info : Atomicorp.com WAF Rules: Attack Blocked - command in REQUEST_URI or Argument
> message : Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "(?:;|/|\| )(?:\b(?:cat|ls|perl|uname|pwd|cp|tclsh8?|cpp|f(?:etch|tp)|python|chown|rm|ping|rsync|rdiff-backup|scp|(?:w|ftp)get|curl|lin

In my blade file, I have a hidden input to which I send the cropped image from the croppie javascript and which allows me to retrieve the image in my Laravel controller. Here is my code:

```
<form action="{{ route('card.store') }}"method="POST" novalidate autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input id="title" name="title" type="text">
    <input id="imgCrop" name="img_crop" type="hidden" />
    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

```
$('.upload-result').on('click', function(ev) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
        type: 'canvas',
        size: {width: 1920, height: 1280},
        format: 'jpeg',
        quality: 0.7
    }).then(function(resp) {
        $('#imgCrop').val(resp);
        $('#imgPreview').removeClass('d-none');
        $('#imgPreview').attr("src", $('#imgCrop').val());
    });
});
```

I spent many hours searching for a solution to this problem, including on the forums, but without success.
Does anyone know of a solution to resolve this problem please?

Comment: `when I send the cropped image to my controller` <<<=== in your jquery I don't see the route that you're using for your controller. `the server firewall interprets it most of the time as an attack and the server returns a 403 error` <<<=== explain 'most of the time'. Also check the 'console' tab of your devtools when that 403 happens. Check for red text. Maybe check nginx access log when that happens. Update your original question with those details

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just edited my post to add my form and what the firewall tells me.
"explain 'most of the time'." ==> Some pictures are uploaded without problem but in most of the time, I get the 403 error ...

Comment: Great job with that extra info. I'll paste a tiny piece of the pattern: `Pattern match "(?:;|/|\| )` <<<=== your webserver looks for those patterns in your filename (?) (request_uri) And if that pattern matches, it will give the 403 error. So now it's really important what you're sending to your backend, but even if it contains `ls` in the filename (?) (request_uri), it will give the 403.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "I'll paste a tiny piece of the pattern" please ? Is it an advice to paste this somewhere in my code ? It seems that Croppie sends the cropped image encoded in base64 and that the pattern sometimes causes issue. Is it  possible to edit this encoded cropped image to avoid matching the pattern ?

Comment: Look at what it says after this message: `ID : 340029 Sévérité : CRITICALLabel : - info : Atomicorp.com WAF Rules: Attack Blocked - command in REQUEST_URI or Argument message : Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match`, it is a pattern. If your Request_Uri or argument matches that pattern, a 403 error occurs

Comment: I understand, my Request_Uri sometimes matches the pattern and then the 403 error occurs. So I only see two solutions : 1) turn off the WAF Rule(s) (not the good solution I guess ...)  - 2) Convert what Croppie creates in something safe for the firewall but I don't find how to do this ...

Comment: Find out how crappie is transferring its content to the backend. It should be a POST request, not a GET. Find out the route, that goes with your controller (paste that entire route) then change the method to PUT or POST. Let it go wrong and look at the error message